# Checkbox is not checking/unchecking inside change event of dropdown using jquery in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "form" }))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Roles",newSelectList((IEnumerable<EmployeeManagementSystem.DAO.RoleMaster>)ViewData["Roles"], "RoleId", "RoleName"), "Select Role", new { @id = "ddlRole" })
    <table id="sample_editable_1">
        <tbody>
            @{                                
                var i = 0;
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="display: none">@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.privilegeId, new { @id = "hdnPrivilegeId" + i })
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBox("CheckBox",false, new { @id = "chkRolePrivilege" + i ,@name="PrivilegeCheckBox"})
                        </td>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(modelITem => item.privilegeName, item.privilegeName, new { @id = "privilegeName" + i, Value = item.privilegeName })
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

I need to check the checkboxes according to the privileges of the role.But the checkboxes are not checked/unchecked inside the change event of dropdown using jquery. But the check boxes able to be checked inside the `$(document).ready(function()` but when we do it inside a change event or something its checked attribute is not working and all other attribute such as disabled etc are working fine.

```
    $("#ddlRole").change(function () {
      var roleId = 0;
            var privilegeListName = "";
            var row = $(this).parent().parent();
            roleId = $('#ddlRole :selected').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Privilege/GetPrivilegesByRoleId?RoleId=" + roleId,
                type: 'Get',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                            if ($('#sample_editable_1 tr #privilegeName' + i).text() == data[j].privilegeName.trim()) {

                                $('#chkRolePrivilege' + i).attr('checked', true);
                                alert("true");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("false");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              });      
            });
```

Comment: i have edited the question...in that i am not getting that    $('#chkRolePrivilege' + i).attr('checked', true);    checked/unchecked

Comment: are you seeing alerts (true or false)?

Comment: all working as I want except the checkbox attribute checked...i am seeing alert(true) too

Comment: All other attributes of the checkboxes are working .If we disable checkbox its done but the checked attribute is not checking or unchecking

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that your data returns a list like

Role = {'privilegeName1', 'privilegeName3'}

```
success: function(data){
   var listRoles = data.Role;
   var cnt = listRoles.length;
   for(var i = 0; i< cnt; i++){
      var privilege = listRoles[i];    // listRole[1] = privilegeName1
      var rId = $.Trim(privilege.replace('privilegeName',''));  //1
      $('#chkRolePrivilege' + rId).attr('checked', true); //chkRolePrivilege1 checked
   }
}
```

Basically what you really need in the list is just the id of the checkboxes you want checked. If you would set the id of your checkbox the same as the database id of your privilegeName then the replacing and trimming won't be necessary.

**EDIT**

Alternative would be

```
$('#chkRolePrivilege' + rId).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

or use .prop

```
$('#chkRolePrivilege' + rId).prop('checked', true);
$('#chkRolePrivilege' + rId).prop('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: Idea was good but I already said that I don't have any problem with the code i have problem in checking the check box.In your case its with..$('#chkRolePrivilege' + rId).attr('checked', true); Its not getting checked.

Answer (score 0):

I just do a minor change in your existing Code, i set Checked attribute as Checked rather than true. some times it Works. Please try this once:

```
("#ddlRole").change(function () {
          var roleId = 0;
                var privilegeListName = "";
                var row = $(this).parent().parent();
                roleId = $('#ddlRole :selected').val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/api/Privilege/GetPrivilegesByRoleId?RoleId=" + roleId,
                    type: 'Get',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {

                        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                            for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                                if ($('#sample_editable_1 tr #privilegeName' + i).text() == data[j].privilegeName.trim()) {

                                    $('#chkRolePrivilege' + i).attr('checked', 'checked');
                                    alert("true");
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("false");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  });      
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help: razor generates two inputs for Html.CheckBox with same name attribute. The second input has type=hidden and stores value = true/false. It is done for sending not checked value.

Comment: I too have a doubt that I am not checking the correct checkbox.But how it can be resolved